# Facebook subdomain issue

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm having problems getting fb connect working on subdomains. the connect button comes up fine, but after it authenicates, the popup just goes blank and no action happens after that. I set the base domain for the app that facebook required for subdomains to work.

Error Info:

For this example look at [test.edited.com](http://test.edited.com/test.php)

I get the following error in firebug

[Exception... "Component is not available" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Users/stan/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/2zn7fi01.default/extensions/%7Be0204bd5-9d31-402b-a99d-a6aa8ffebdca%7D/components/nsSessionStore3.js :: sss_saveState :: line 1942" data: no]
anonymous()6pz91fhb.js (line 598)
anonymous("http://www.benescribe.com/xd_receiver.htm", Object uid=668556638, Object feedStorySettings=Object inFacebook=false, 1, "benescribe.com", Object name=publicSessionData, "http://test.benescribe.com/test.php", Object name=xd_comm_id)6pz91fhb.js (line 595)
anonymous()login_st...eiver.htm (line 22)
anonymous()6pz91fhb.js (line 125)
anonymous()6pz91fhb.js (line 54)
[Break on this error] this._writeFile(this._sessionFile, oState.toSource());\n

It works fine for subdirectories, and I'm not sharing data between subdomains, just one domain and subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the document.domain to equal your page without the subdomain. This might work, but I don't know why it would.

```
document.domain = "benescribe.com";
```

Comment: Nope,doesn't seem to do anything